# Anonymous functions in laravel3 lists failed to run in a2hosting's php, run well in local php

Tags: php, hosting, closures, anonymous-function, laravel-3

In a2hosting, When I run artisan migration, I got this error message:

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/letsmakan/laravel/database/query.php on line 677`

And the migration failed to run because it try to execute migrations that already ran. This error also affect the web application that using eloquent relationship methods.

I create a simple task to test this error:

```
class Test_Query_Lists_Task {

  public function run($arguments)
  {
    print_r( DB::table('laravel_migrations')->where_bundle('application')->lists('name') );
  }

}
```

Here is the result in my local laptop:

```
$ php artisan test_query_lists
Array
(
    [0] => 2012_12_30_170932_create_session_table
    [1] => 2013_01_20_014710_create_users_table
    [2] => 2013_01_20_014725_create_restaurants_table
    [3] => 2013_01_20_093320_create_reviews_table
    [4] => 2013_01_20_093329_create_menus_table
    [5] => 2013_01_20_093410_create_taxonomies_table
    [6] => 2013_02_08_005320_create_restaurant_taxonomy_table
    [7] => 2013_03_30_161928_staple_restaurants_table
    [8] => 2013_04_01_083523_staple_users_table
    [9] => 2013_04_05_101718_add_column_to_restaurants_table
    [10] => 2013_04_05_151456_create_landmarks_table
    [11] => 2013_04_08_220234_create_restaurants_associations_tables
    [12] => 2013_04_08_225949_create_review_comments_table
    [13] => 2013_04_08_230243_create_badges_table
    [14] => 2013_04_08_230613_create_guides_table
    [15] => 2013_04_08_231201_create_restaurant_photos_table
    [16] => 2013_04_10_122201_fix_relation
    [17] => 2013_04_15_193712_add_cities_table
    [18] => 2013_04_23_070312_add_provinces
    [19] => 2013_04_25_230524_add_province_and_city_foreign_keys
    [20] => 2013_05_05_010828_create_pages_table
    [21] => 2013_05_05_151440_add_en_column_to_page
    [22] => 2013_05_11_215824_add_navigations_table
    [23] => 2013_05_11_220719_fix_related_pages_table
    [24] => 2013_05_11_230543_add_tag_to_navigations
    [25] => 2013_05_12_105057_rename_navigation_to_link
    [26] => 2013_05_14_175304_add_business_owner
    [27] => 2013_05_15_184403_add_timezone_to_users_table
    [28] => 2013_05_19_172729_add_user_id_to_restaurant_photo
    [29] => 2013_06_16_075032_add_authentications_table
    [30] => 2013_06_17_121416_add_uid_to_authentications_table
    [31] => 2013_06_22_035428_add_photo_description_to_restaurant_photos
    [32] => 2013_06_22_085548_add_is_approved_to_restaurant_photos
    [33] => 2013_06_23_193459_add_fields_to_users_table
    [34] => 2013_06_25_084751_add_is_approved_to_review
    [35] => 2013_06_25_101550_add_spam_mark_to_reviews
    [36] => 2013_06_25_105936_add_slug_to_restaurants
    [37] => 2013_06_25_123441_add_picture_to_menus
    [38] => 2013_06_25_124645_staple_guides_table
    [39] => 2013_06_25_125905_add_user_id_to_guide
    [40] => 2013_06_25_142312_staple_guides_table
    [41] => 2013_06_25_143651_staple_menus_table
    [42] => 2013_06_25_150150_add_like_count_to_restaurants
    [43] => 2013_06_27_153034_staple_taxonomies_table
    [44] => 2013_06_28_162745_create_ip2location_db5s_table
    [45] => 2013_06_28_203807_add_region_name_to_provinces_table
    [46] => 2013_07_01_164548_add_slug_to_guides
    [47] => 2013_07_01_233517_add_like_count_to_guides
    [48] => 2013_07_14_073249_add_province_and_city_to_users
    [49] => 2013_07_18_072923_add_likes_table
    [50] => 2013_07_18_132939_add_glike_table
)
```

Here is result in a2hosting:

```
$ php artisan test_query_lists --env=beta
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] => 
    [13] => 
    [14] => 
    [15] => 
    [16] => 
    [17] => 
    [18] => 
    [19] => 
    [20] => 
    [21] => 
    [22] => 
    [23] => 
    [24] => 
    [25] => 
    [26] => 
    [27] => 
    [28] => 
    [29] => 
    [30] => 
    [31] => 
    [32] => 
    [33] => 
    [34] => 
    [35] => 
    [36] => 
    [37] => 
    [38] => 
    [39] => 
    [40] => 
    [41] => 
    [42] => 
    [43] => 
    [44] => 
    [45] => 
    [46] => 
    [47] => 
    [48] => 
    [49] => 
)
```

when using php 5.4:

```
$ php5.4 artisan test_query_lists --env=beta
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/letsmaka/beta/laravel/database/query.php on line 677
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] => 
    [13] => 
    [14] => 
    [15] => 
    [16] => 
    [17] => 
    [18] => 
    [19] => 
    [20] => 
    [21] => 
    [22] => 
    [23] => 
    [24] => 
    [25] => 
    [26] => 
    [27] => 
    [28] => 
    [29] => 
    [30] => 
    [31] => 
    [32] => 
    [33] => 
    [34] => 
    [35] => 
    [36] => 
    [37] => 
    [38] => 
    [39] => 
    [40] => 
    [41] => 
    [42] => 
    [43] => 
    [44] => 
    [45] => 
    [46] => 
    [47] => 
    [48] => 
    [49] => 
)
```

The version of php in my local:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.3 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2013 18:19:45) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

In a2hosting:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.23 (cli) (built: Apr 23 2013 11:28:59) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies

$ php5.4 --version
PHP 5.4.13 (cli) (built: Apr 22 2013 17:57:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Here is the snippets of `lists` methods in `query.php`

```
/**
 * Get an array with the values of a given column.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return array
 */
public function lists($column, $key = null)
{
  $columns = (is_null($key)) ? array($column) : array($column, $key);

  $results = $this->get($columns);

  // First we will get the array of values for the requested column.
  // Of course, this array will simply have numeric keys. After we
  // have this array we will determine if we need to key the array
  // by another column from the result set.
  $values = array_map(function($row) use ($column)
  {
    return $row->$column;

  }, $results);

  // If a key was provided, we will extract an array of keys and
  // set the keys on the array of values using the array_combine
  // function provided by PHP, which should give us the proper
  // array form to return from the method.
  if ( ! is_null($key) && count($results))
  {
    return array_combine(array_map(function($row) use ($key)
    {
      return $row->$key;

    }, $results), $values);
  }

  return $values;
}
```

Line 677 is this code:
`return $row->$column;`

The errors just started occurred in the last few weeks. Before that, all migration ran successfully without error.

Why the anonymous function that used by lists method failed to run? What kind of settings that need to be enabled in php to make it work?

Thanks.

UPDATE

I try to debug this problems by add this:

```
675     $values = array_map(function($row) use ($column)
676     {
677       print_r($row);
678       return $row->$column;
679     
680     }, $results);
```

In my local, I got this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => 2012_12_30_170932_create_session_table
)
```

But in a2hosting, I got this instead:

```
Array
(   
    [name] => 2012_12_30_170932_create_session_table
    [0] => 2012_12_30_170932_create_session_table
)
```

How come the php behavior get different and how to make it act like other standard php?

Answer (score 0):

By adding fetch setting to database setting, now the laravel database class behavior the same across platform:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PDO Fetch Style
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
| stdClass object; however, you may wish to retrieve records as arrays
| instead of objects. Here you can control the PDO fetch style of the
| database queries run by your application.
|
*/

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
```